# looking for context of words inside corpus categories doesn't work

Tags: python, nltk

I wrote this little script to find the context of the 10 most frequent words in my corpus. But it doesn't work and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.The tien_frequentste(mijn_corpus) definition works on it's own.

```
tienfrequentste = tien_frequentste(mijncorpus)
def context (corpus, most_freq):
   for category in corpus.categories():
     print "Context voor" , category, ":"
       for word in most_freq:
           print nltk.Text(corpus.words(categories=category)).concordance(word)
```

UPDATE:
I get an error message on traceback
for `context(corpus, most_freq)`,
for `category in corpus.categories()`,
for `self.init()`
and `in_init`. 
And an `AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.
No idea what these errors mean..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/...document.py", line 92, in <module> context (mijn_corpus, tienfrequentste)

 File "/Users/...document.py", line 87, in context for category in corpus.categories(): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk.corpus.reader.api.py, line 317, in categories self.init().

File "/Users/...document.py", line 87, in context for category in corpus.categories(): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk.corpus.reader.api.py, line 289, in_init category = re.match(self._pattern, file id).group(1)

attributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute "group"
```

Comment: Is it just not working? Are you getting and error? The more info you provide the easier it is to help

Comment: @Gareth Webber I edited my question with info on the error messages.

Comment: Why don't you simply copy-paste the error here, it'll be a lot easier to understand the problem, knowing the exact trackback

Comment: That's another problem, each time I try to copy or paste anything from Python it shuts down and reports an error message.

Comment: @paddila since copy-paste doesn't worked I copied the error messages by hand. Hope this makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

Does your corpus have categories and is `most_freq` a list of strings? The following example works:

```
from nltk.corpus import reuters
for category in reuters.categories():
print "context voor", category, " : "
for word in ["get", "have", "do"]:
    print nltk.Text(reuters.words(categories=category)).concordance(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the regular expression that assigns corpus files to categories. It's stumbling on a filename that doesn't match the regexp pattern. If you're using a standard NLTK corpus with categories, you must have put an extra file in the corpus directory. If you're using your own corpus, it's misconfigured.

Incidentally, `concordance()` prints its output and returns `None`. If you use `print` with it, you'll see a whole bunch of `None` values.